# Proper use of 'of such'?

Tags: grammaticality

Is this proper use of *'of such'*?

> ...providing resilience to removing keywords or blocking
>   the use **of such**.

Comment: Potentially (depending on context). Why couldn't it be?

Comment: Yep, no problems with it, though there are alternatives to make it clearer (especially for non-native readers). Example: *"providing resilience to the removal or blocking of keywords."*

Comment: I agree that it's correct, but it seems to be an overly fancy way to say "providing resilience to removing keywords or to blocking their use."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be correct usage of the phrase in question; I'm not sure I like the construction "...resilience to..." - but before I can comment on that, I would want to see the entire context.

As given, the use of 'of such' here refers to 'keywords'; that is, "...removing keywords or blocking the use of keywords.".

Comment: As this answer demonstrates, using 'of such' saves little in this situation. It's like using 'the aforementioned' or 'the above-captioned" instead of just reminding us what you are referring to. Would it kill the writer to say 'blocking or removing keywords'?